# Rescuing and catching at the same time

Tags: ruby, error-handling, try-catch, throw

If I wanted to both rescue a potential error and catch a potential throw, how should I nest them? Are the two below equivalent, and it is just a matter of preference?

```
begin
  catch(:some_throw) do
    ...
  end
rescue SomeError
  ...
end


catch(:some_throw) do
  begin
    ...
  rescue SomeError
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: @WandMaker They are not alternatives.

Comment: @WandMaker I didn't realize the typo. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its an opinion-based question, and one can argue either way.  So, in my opinion...

If you are planning to return a value via `throw`, then, second option seems useful as it will let you `rescue` an error and `throw` some kind of default value.

Even if you were using `throw` and `catch` just to manage loop iterations and breaking out of it on certain conditions, second option still seems more readable and encapsulates all the logic inside the `catch` block.

Answer (score 1):

They are not entirely equivalent. With the first alternative, the `catch` will only intercept values being thrown in the `begin` clause, while the second includes ones from `rescue` too.

---

That being said, if you are in the case, when the two are equivalent (aka you don't throw `:some_throw` in the `rescue` clause):

- The argument for the first alternative would be that we tend to think that `begin` - `rescue` blocks enclose *"regular"* statements. `throw` - `catch` being rarely used and having a non-error semantic are more *"regular"*-y.
- The argument for the second alternative would be that one should strive to enclose the least amount (only the possibly failing) of code in `begin` - `rescue` clauses.

Personally, I like the first one better.